# Capturar varios parametros en php redirigiendo en .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo que capturar varios parámetros que recibo en la ruta y variables. La petición que recibo es como la siguiente:

```
https://www.webejemplo.com/cita/departamento/125?fechadesde=11/04/2022&fechahasta=21/04/2022
```

De ella tengo que extraer el **departamento** (125), la **fecha desde** (11/04/202) y la **fecha hasta** (21/04/2022).

Mediante el HTACCESS redirijo la petición de la siguiente forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    
RewriteRule ^cita/departamento/(.*)$ cita.php?departamento=$1
```

Mi problema es que, al redirigir la petición, aunque en cita.php recibo correctamente el parámetro departamento, **se pierden los parámetros de fecha desde y hasta**.

¿Cómo puedo redirigir la petición de forma que en cita.php pueda recibir todos los parámetros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun mi entender, **no te hace falta redirigir la petición** en el .htaccess.

Lo que necesitas es, una vez esa redirección consigue entrar en cita.php, gestionar los parámetros mediante la variable **`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`**, la cual te va a devolver toda la URL de este modo:

```
/cita/departamento/125?fechadesde=11/04/2022&fechahasta=21/04/2022
```

A partir de aquí puedes jugar con esa cadena como prefieras para sacar los parámetros.

El método más sencillo que se me ocurre es usar [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para desechar la primera parte de la cadena hasta el interrogante `?`, combinado con [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php) para generar un nuevo array que denominaremos **$params** y que contendrá las claves y valores de esos parámetros del siguiente modo:

```
parse_str(explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1], $params);
```

Si luego hacemos un `print_r($params);` nos va a devolver esto:

```
Array
(
    [fechadesde] => 11/04/2022
    [fechahasta] => 21/04/2022
)
```

con lo cual ya podremos acceder a los parámetros mediante:

```
$params['fechadesde']
$params['fechahasta']
```